# Finding 1000 linear interpolated values between every number of a list in Python

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python and am stuck on a problem. I have two lists of 60 floating point numbers, lets call them start and end. The numbers in both the lists are not in an increasing or decreasing order.

```
start = [ ] //60 floating point numbers
end = [ ] // 60 floating numbers
```

I would like to find 1000 interpolated values between `start[0]` and `end[0]` and repeat the process for all 60 values of list. How do I go about it?

Comment: This is an interpolation question. Not a python question.

Comment: Also, it is not clear what did you try so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a list comprehension and using `numpy.linspace`

```
import numpy as np
[np.linspace(first, last, 1000) for first, last in zip(start, end)]
```

As a small example (with fewer values)

```
>>> start = [1, 5, 10]
>>> end = [2, 10, 20]
>>> [np.linspace(first, last, 5) for first, last in zip(start, end)]
[array([ 1.  ,  1.25,  1.5 ,  1.75,  2.  ]),
 array([  5.  ,   6.25,   7.5 ,   8.75,  10.  ]),
 array([ 10. ,  12.5,  15. ,  17.5,  20. ])]
```